# How to stop other functions from running when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to challenge myself and made an Etch a Sketch, basically when i hover on the divs I created their color change, I made a button so when I click it and hover over the div the color will be different(random rgb) from other divs(each div different color), I made the other button to leave a trail to the past divs I hovered and a button so when I hover over divs they all have the same color. I want the other functions to stop when I click a button for example when I click Random Color button and call randomColor function I want the trialColor and normalColor funtions to stop.

Jsfiddle code
https://jsfiddle.net/6m6vuqm1/

```
<div class="header">
<button class="buttons" id="color-button" value="Default">Default</button>
<button class="buttons" id="random-color" value="Random Color">Random Color</button>
<button class="buttons" id="trail-color" value="Trail Color">Trail Color</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var userAnswer = parseInt(prompt("Enter an number between 1 and 60"));
var squares = "<div class='square'></div>";
    var squareCount = userAnswer * userAnswer;
    var dimensions = 960 / userAnswer;
    for(var i = 0; i < squareCount; i++ ){
        $(".the-grid").append(squares);
    }
        $(".square").width(dimensions);
        $(".square").height(dimensions);

// Create normal color
function normalColor(){
    $(".square").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#513684");
    });
}

// Create trail color
function trailColor(){
    $(".square").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({
            "background-color":"#000",
            "opacity":"1"
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(10000,0);
    });
}

// Create Random Color
function randomColor(){
    $(".square").mouseenter(function(){
        var hex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F"];
        var hexColor = "#";
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            var randomHex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
            hexColor += hex[randomHex];
        }
        $(this).css("background-color",hexColor);
    });
}
//Clear grid
function clearGrid(){
    $("#clear-button").click(function(){
        $(".square").css("background-color","transparent");
    }); 
}
    // Events

$("#random-color").on("click",function(){
    $(".header").off("click","#color-button",normalColor);
    $(".header").off("click","#trail-color",trailColor);
    randomColor();
});

$("#color-button").on("click",function(){
    $(".header").off("click","#random-color",randomColor);
    $(".header").off("click","#trail-color",trailColor);
    normalColor();
});

$("#trail-color").on("click",function(){
    $(".header").off("click","#random-color",randomColor);
    $(".header").off("click","#color-button",normalColor);
    trailColor();
});

$("#clear-button").on("click",clearGrid);


});
```

Comment: It seems that you are only removing the event handlers for the other buttons and not actually stopping the other functions. Can you include the code for the other functions?

Comment: What about a global variable and a basic if statement? I don't know of any other way you can stop functions. Unless you unbind their triggers, but I am guessing you don't want to do that.

Comment: When i click a button the function starts but when I click the other button and call the other function the functions of past buttons don't stop. I edited it and put all the javascript code in.

Comment: I agree. A simple conditional statement would work, nested perhaps in a `setInterval` function to periodically check if the condition is still `true`. And it would be best, if you have all of your code already, to post it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so you we can edit it.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You attached the events in .square element. To stop events with off() or unbind() you must attach them in the elements that have the event triggers:

```
$('.element').on('click', function() {});
$('#other-element').off('click'); // this not dettach the above event.
```

To detach correctly:

```
$('.element').on('click', function() {});
$('.element').off('click');
```

You can use unbind too

```
$('.element').unbind('click');
```

Comment: What are you making? This solves the problem.try this exact code:  $('.square').unbind(); and then try it. The event must to detach inmediately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the functions directly to hover, pass in a pointer to a function. Then change the underlying function as needed.

```
// This is just sample code

function normalColorLogic(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#513684");
}

function normalColor(){
    $(".square").hover(function(){ normalColorLogic(); });
}

function randomColor() {
    // random color logic
    // …

    // Now, let's turn off normalColor
    normalColorLogic = function(){}; 
}

// When you want to turn normalColor back on
normalColorLogic = function(){ $(this).css("background-color","#513684"); };
```